# Add data frame / rows in every change of value

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, lapply

I'm working with a list of data frames (named b2), which has the following structure.

```r
b2<- split(resumen,resumen$Clave.Cliente)
b2$'902'
```

[image: data.frame]

semana2 is a single data.frame (not into list) with the following structure:

```r
semana2<- as.data.frame(seq(from = as.Date("2018-02-05"), to = as.Date("2020-06-25"), by = 7))
names(semana2)<- 'semana'
semana2$total.de.unidades<- NA
semana2$total.de.unidades<- as.numeric(semana2$total.de.unidades)
```

[image: semana2]

What I need to do is, **for each change of value** in column *Clave.Articulo*, bind_rows or add the data.frame semana2 below.

The result would be something like this.

```r
b3<- lapply(b2, function(x) bind_rows(x,semana2))
b3$'000053'
```

[image: output]

As you can see, I bind the rows at the bottom of the data frame, instead of bind it in every change of 'Clave.Articulo'.

You would help me a lot if you can do it. I suggest to use dplyr::bind_rows for this task, but I let you to your consideration. The result will be a bigger dataframe.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: (1) Please learn how to format code, it can make a difference: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. (2) Please don't expect us to either parse your *image* for usable data or generate our own data to mimic you data, there are too many places where it will go wrong. Please just provide a *real* sample of your data using `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`.

Comment: Hello Pablo, welcome to StackOverflow. Please, share a small sample of your dataset, you can type `dput(head(dataset))` in the console (assuming your dataframe name is "dataset") and copy the output in your question. And please, could you show your expected output? Help us to help you.

Comment: Hey Pablo, I agree that your example isn't really reproducible, but perhaps this helps you: you can check for a "change" in your column by doing `b2$change <- b2$Clave.Articulo != dplyr::lag(b2$Clave.Articulo,1)` and potentially take it from there. might make sense to filter the dataframe, retaining the changed rows only and then cross join `semana2`